# Can't run visudo within Docker; sudoers file does not exist

Tags: sudo, docker, visudo

Ubuntu n00b here. I am tinkering with a Docker container that I created using the following simple Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu
CMD ["tail","-f","/dev/null"]
```

Inside the container, as the root user, I try running `visudo` and get the following response:

> bash: visudo: command not found

I ran `ls /etc` and it seems I don't have a sudoers file either.

Is there something special I should have put in my Dockerfile to make these exist?

Comment: Why would you want to use `sudo` in a docker container ?

Comment: @RoVo My next step is going to be setting up other users in the container.

Comment: Just asking, as normal use case would be one service per container => only a single user needed ... But of course you're free to do whatever ;-)

Comment: `visudo` is meant to interactively edit the `sudoers` file. If you really need to change sudo privs in a container, you only need to `COPY` at container build time a `sudoers` file that you have prepared outside the container.

Answer (score 2):

I worked it out from [another answer](https://superuser.com/a/605692/14848): `sudo` is not installed by default. To install `sudo`:

```
apt-get update
apt-get install sudo
```

Answer (score 1):

When you built the container, you are root so you can create users without sudo.

If you are deriving a container image that already has a `USER` directive, you can still become root again with `USER root` before using privileged commands. You can later issue another `USER` directive to become the execution user again. In other words:

An image that sets a non privilege user:

```
# "plainuser" image
FROM debian
RUN groupadd -g 1000 appgroup && useradd -g appgroup -u 1000 appuser
USER appuser
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/bin/id"]
```

Run with `docker run --rm plainuser` to check that it indeed runs with user `appuser`.

Let's derive it:

```
# "otheruser" image
FROM plainuser
USER root  # Become root again
RUN groupadd -g 1001 appgroup2 && useradd -g appgroup2 -u 1001 appuser2
USER appuser2 # Set new execution user
```

Run with `docker run --rm otheruser`.

Comment: Thanks, this is all very useful info. Doesn't directly answer my question (which my answer does), but adds useful info for a n00b like me :-)

Comment: Still can't figure out why you need sudoers in a container, and even less visudo. IMHO you're doing something the wrong way.

Comment: To satisfy your curiosity, I'm working on a Windows computer. We are creating a package that needs to be installed on a clean Ubuntu device, including setup of different users. So I need the Docker container to be able to test and tinker with our installation script.

Comment: Best test that with a VM, containers and VM are different animals, VMs are much closer to individual devices (for instance you wouldn't need to install `sudo` in a VM, nor in your target system...). This doesn't explain the `visudo` requirement, even in that case you can copy a `sudoers` file or edit it with a script or add your stuff in `/etc/sudoers.d`.